# How to Sort the order of row for multi header columns?

Tags: eclipse, nattable

I Just taken NatTable example to understand my requirement.
We have an multi column headers in my NatTable, which i need to sort the group of header columns.

Pls refre the image

[image]

How to sort the rows of multi column headers.
Suppose if one of the row of column header contains numerical value, then also should sort properly

EX:

```
Address        Person 
1 | 10 | 2    1| 12 | 13

Then it should sort in this way..

Address        Person 
1 | 2 | 10    1| 12 | 13
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want to show the columns in a sorted way. Is that correct?
If so you need to implement that yourself, e.g. using a sortable structure for columns. The default column header dataprovider is static and does not support any sorting capabilities.